# How to make a 5 stars review widget with an incremental of 0.5 in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have the widget fully working with the 5 stars, the data binding and the interface as follows:

```
import SwiftUI


struct mainView: View {
    @State var rating: Double = 0.0
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            RatingView(rating: $rating)
            Text("\(String(format: "%.1f", rating))")
                .font(.system(size: 30))
        }.background(.mint)
    }
}

struct RatingView: View {
    @Binding var rating: Double

    var offColor = Color.white
    var onColor = Color("AccentColor")
    var starHalf = Image(systemName: "star.leadinghalf.filled")
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(1..<6) { number in
                Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                    .foregroundColor(number > Int(self.rating) ? self.offColor : self.onColor)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.rating = Double(number)
                        selectionChanged()
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        mainView()
    }
}
```

Works perfect, but  have no idea how can I implement to have a 0.5 increment, and to change the icon for the half star. there is nothing like .onHelfLeftTapGesture() I can use?

Comment: look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71061258/swiftui-drag-gesture-coordinates/71062101#71062101

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it reasonably with a tap gesture, unless you want to go a half star at a time. But using a different mechanism will make it flow better. Simply use a `Slider` with an `.opacity(0.1)` so it works, but is transparent, in an `.overlay()` that is keyed to the stars:

```
struct RatingsView: View {
    let ratingsArray: [Double]
    let color: Color
    @Binding var rating: Double
    
    init(rating: Binding<Double>, maxRating: Int = 5, starColor: Color = .yellow) {
        _rating = rating
        ratingsArray = Array(stride(from: 0.0, through: Double(max(1, maxRating)), by: 0.5))
        color = starColor
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(ratingsArray, id: \.self) { ratingElement in
                    if ratingElement > 0 {
                        if Int(exactly: ratingElement) != nil && ratingElement <= rating {
                            Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                                .foregroundColor(color)
                        } else if Int(exactly: ratingElement) == nil && ratingElement == rating {
                            Image(systemName: "star.leadinghalf.fill")
                                .foregroundColor(color)
                        } else if Int(exactly: ratingElement) != nil && rating + 0.5 != ratingElement {
                            Image(systemName: "star")
                                .foregroundColor(color)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .overlay(
                Slider(value: $rating, in: 0.0...ratingsArray.last!, step: 0.5)
                    .tint(.clear)
                    .opacity(0.1)
            )
        }
        .onAppear {
            rating = Int(exactly: rating) != nil ? rating : Double(Int(rating)) + 0.5
        }
    }
}
```

No, I didn't just come up with this, but had come up with this before Christmas to play with the idea. This is the code I came up with.

Comment: That is not bad solution. Maybe the best will be to convince both solutions, so the user can scroll to half or tap to full!